# Trying to understand logic behind map method

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to understand the logic of using array methods within Map functions (such as push, slice, etc). Below, I have a function that is trying to add an element in the middle of a 2D array, but it comes out completely blank. Not sure what I am missing

```
function array () {

let numbers = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
// Attempted outcome = [[1, 2, "Hello", 3], [4, 5, "Hello", 6], [7, 8, "Hello", 9]]

let newNumbers = numbers.map(function (row) {
  return [row.slice(2, 0, "Hello")]
})

Logger.log(newNumbers);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let newNumbers = numbers.map(function (row) {
  return [row.slice(2, 0, "Hello")]
})
```

#### To:

```
let newNumbers = numbers.map(function (row) {
  row.splice(2, 0, "Hello");
  return row;
});
```

or, in this case, the following modification might be able to be used.

```
let newNumbers = numbers.map(([a, b, ...c]) => [a, b, "Hello", ...c]);
```

#### Testing:

```js
let numbers = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
// Attempted outcome = [[1, 2, "Hello", 3], [4, 5, "Hello", 6], [7, 8, "Hello", 9]]

let newNumbers = numbers.map(function (row) {
  row.splice(2, 0, "Hello");
  return row;
});

console.log(newNumbers);
```

#### Reference:

- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: @Alexa Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.